# User command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is It possible for a user to input a command in python through the use of a function?
like this:

```
#run - command to send user input
def run(execute):
    execute

#program example
command = input("Type in your command: ")
run(command)
```

further more, a loop could be added to create a infinite loop until "END" is entered, since this feature is already in IDLE, im talking about running a .py file and using it to create a file for example

a user could enter `create=open("file.txt","w")` but would it work? if not how could it be made to work so that the user could use commands created by the programmer, for example in this code:

```
#run - command to send user input
def run(execute):
    execute

#Example command
def example(text):
    f = open("user.txt", "w+")
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

#program example
command = input("Type in your command: ")
run(command)
```

would it work if the user typed in `example("hello world!")`?

Comment: +1 to @iCodez for the warning: That is HOW you do it. BUT YOU HARDLY EVER WANT TO TRUST THE USERS INPUT!!!!!(they could put really really bad stuff in and delete everything ). This screams XY problem. WHY do you want to allow users to input commands?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#exec) built-in:

```
>>> exec(input('Input a command: '))
Input a command: print(1+1)
2
>>>
```

Note however that this should be used with cation--it will run whatever you put in there as real Python code.

Comment: i think you might mean `raw_input` ?

Comment: @Tehtris - Not with Python 3.x, which is what he is using.

Comment: ahem... what i meant to say is.... if you were doing it in 2.7 it would be `raw_input()` :)